# Xcode error kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to format $123,123 USA currency in an app displaying properties on a map. The number show $(null) should show the #

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') with an expression of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')
>
> Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum CFNumberFormatterStyle' to different enumeration type 'NSNumberFormatterStyle' (aka 'enum NSNumberFormatterStyle')

```
cell.imgViewPropertyType.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"for_sale"];
NSInteger *intPrice = [theProperty.priceSale integerValue];
NSNumber *tempPrice = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:intPrice];
NSString *price = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:tempPrice numberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this. Note that `intPrice` is not a pointer and hence you need to declare as `NSInteger intPrice` instead of `NSInteger *intPrice`. That is the reason for the error which you are getting.

```
cell.imgViewPropertyType.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"for_sale"];
NSInteger intPrice = [theProperty.priceSale integerValue];
NSNumber *tempPrice = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:intPrice];
```

As rmaddy pointed below, you can also use below line.

```
NSNumber *tempPrice = @(intPrice);
```

Regarding second error about `CFNumberFormatterStyle`, `localizedStringFromNumber` accepts `NSNumberFormatterStyle` and not type `CFNumberFormatterStyle`. You are trying to pass wrong type of style there. Try with `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`.

```
NSString *price = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:tempPrice numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

Comment: Use modern syntax: `NSNumber *tempPrice = @(intPrice);`

Comment: @rmaddy, True. I would have usually used that. But wanted to show exact issue he had without confusing him. So left that part as it is.

Comment: thanks - got it to work but with another question, what is "hasPrefix:@"CUP"? when i remove that the price shows other wise no?                                   if ([price hasPrefix:@"CUP"] && [price hasSuffix:@".00"])
                    {
                        newString = [price substringFromIndex:1];
                        newString =  [newString substringToIndex:[newString length]-3];
                        
                    }
                    cell.lblPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",newString];
                    
                }

Comment: @bjornhustrulid, Could you please create that as a new question? It is difficult to understand code from your comment. Also if this answer helped, could you please accept it by clicking on "check mark" next to answer.